# Google Calendar API responds with event 'updated' time as UTC instead of the calendar default of GMT - anyway to force timezone for 'updated?'

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Didn't find any previous threads so am hoping someone lovely has some ideas.

As per the title, the Google Calendar API responds with event 'updated' time as UTC instead of the calendar default of GMT (which the event 'start' or 'end' times are correctly received as.)

This obviously throws everything out of sync so we would be very appreciative if anyone had any ideas of any setting within GCP that allowed us to force their API to use GMT instead of UTC.

(Worth noting: We are using a no-code tool so requesting things in a different timezone appears to be impossible.)

Many thanks in advance if anyone can help!

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question include [example] and describe the issue. Include any errors or data that is needed to show your issue.   Events are inserted in the time zone of the calendar unless you are passing the time zone with your request.  Without seeing your request and the current timezone of the calendar it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @DaImTo
- My appologies, I wasn't sure how to provide an example as as mentioned, the tools we are using are no-code so all code is hidden. 

Anyone should be able to reproduce the issue by simply requesting all/any event from their calendar and they should notice the times returned for event 'start' and 'end' dates are sent using the calendar default timezone, whereas the times returned for the 'updated' field are sent using the UTC timezone. 

Not sure if that helps at all but many thanks if anyone has any ideas re the OP. Cheers!